# how do I solve " Failed building wheel for hdbscan "?

Tags: python, pip, hdbscan

I tried to download Hdbscan using `pip install hdbscan` , I get this :

**ERROR**: Failed building wheel for hdbscan

**ERROR**: Could not build wheels for hdbscan which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

I've tried several solutions, it didn't work tho.

Answer (score 6):

you simply use `conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan` instead of pip

or you can go to : https://anaconda.org/search?q=hdbscan
if the first code doesn't work too.

Answer (score 6):

Try to install the equivalent python3.[x]-dev package.

For ex, for python3.8 use: `sudo apt install python3.8-dev`

Answer (score 0):

You can run build essential to fix your error

> sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to install hdbscan on a notebook instance (it works on aws sagemaker notebook):

```
apt-get install g++-6 --yes    
apt-get install gcc --yes
pip install hdbscan
```